# create table check telephoneNumber (type char) that all characters all is digit?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

create table_name

(
          TelNum char(20)  //all character is digits

)
I'm new in Sql server.
Please help me!

Comment: You need ti clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but I'm thinking `LIKE` with a sort of double-negative, something like this:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TelNum CHECK (TelNum NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

That checks to make sure `TelNum` doesn't contain any characters other than 0 through 9. It sounds a bit confusing, but it's better to specify the characters that *are* allowed, as opposed to the ones that *aren't*.

[SQL Fiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86ef9/8).

Comment: Yes I almost do it.But how about ?when every character I type is digit. Ex: 48708 is true

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're saying that you entered all digits and it was still rejected, it's probably because you defined this field as `char(20)`, which means it __must__ have 20 characters. The solution is to either always enter 20 characters, or make the field `varchar(20)` instead. Here's [another example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/398c0/1).

Comment: Srr.I'm wrong with title.Exactly what I wish is every character I type is digit.

Comment: That's what it does. My statement is just confusing to read. It accepts your input as long as it __doesn't__ contain any characters that are __not__ digits. In other words, it rejects your input if it has non-digits. [Click on this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/398c0/1) and try out a few tests. For example, 48708 works, like you want it to.

Comment: But when I insert something like "00001".It still alert wrong!.And I use char instead of varchar

Comment: Right, because char __requires__ 20 characters. Try '00000000000000000001'. Or switch to varchar.

Comment: ok!You know it.It work for varchar

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. :-)